# How to execute Runnable/Thread in correct sequence

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

Imagine a datastream like this

`A,A,B,A,C,C,C,A,B,A,A,A,B...`

Now lets assume we have a `StreamProcessor` that will handle the stream. We can process A,B,C in parallel but individual As,Bs,Cs have to be processed in sequence.

Example:
Thread 1: Processes all As in sequence
Thread 2: Processes all Bs in sequence
and so on...

So for A,B,C I have a StreamProcessor (SP).

Each of the stream elements has a timestamp and thus can be ordered by time (It actually comes in the correct sequence). The elements have to be processed in time sequence.

So now I split up all my stream elements to their processors (SPA,SPB,SPC).

I have a TreeSet in ever SP where I add the elements.

So whenever there is a new element I basically do this:

```
 public synchronized void onNewElementReceived(Element element) {
        if (element== null) return;
        treeSet.add(element);
        if(treeSet.size()>30) logger.warn("There are many elements queueing up for processing");
        threadPool.execute(() -> process(treeSet.first()));
    }

private synchronized void process(Element element){
    //Do the processing
}
```

This works fine if the stream is slow enough for process to terminate before there is the next element. But what if not? If there are more elements coming how can I make sure that the next element also is the next element that is going to be processed? In the end the operating system decides which Thread is fired when?

**Edit:** For clarity an example where this will fail:

Assume `process()` of A elements takes 1 second to execute. Now if the stream provides As faster then we can process them our treeSet will fill with elements of type A (I just realized it does not because we immediatly fetch it again, hmm another problem) anyway the main problem stays. If we receive elements every 100 ms for example we would request 10 executions of the `process` method, but the order would not be guaranteed anymore, because we do not know, which Runnable is going to be executed first by the system. We only ADDED them in the correct sequence but how to EXECUTE them in the correct sequence?

I could imagine just running a looper thread all the time fetching the first element of the queue and if there is none abort the process. Is that a good approach?

Comment: “We can process A,B,C in parallel but individual A,B,C have to be processed in sequence.” That’s a contradiction. Needs a rewrite for clarity.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the problem? It is pretty hard to understand.

Comment: I just edited the question. So all As have to be processed in sequence. But while doing this Bs can also be processed in parallel. So while an A is processing, a B also can be processed. But not two As at the same time

Comment: > This works fine if the stream is slow enough for process to terminate before there is >> the next element. But what if not?

Can you provide an example? Just to get the idea of the problem.

Comment: I tried to eleborate more on this. See the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it like this (PseudoCode-Like):

```
abstract class StreamProcessor extends Thread{
  private ThreadSafeList<Element> elements;
  void add(Element e) {
    elements.addAtEnd(e);
  }
  @Override
  public void run() {
    while(hasNotFinished()) {
      //If list has element, return the first element and remove it from the list, otherwise block until one is there and then return the first element and remove it.
      Element e = elements.blockingRemoveFirst();
      this.workWith(e);
    }
  }
  abstract void workWith(Element e);
}

class StreamProcessorA extends StreamProcessor {
  @Override
  public void workWith(Element e) {
    //Do something
  }
}
class StreamProcessorB extends StreamProcessor {
  @Override
  public void workWith(Element e) {
    //Do something
  }
}
class StreamProcessorC extends StreamProcessor {
  @Override
  public void workWith(Element e) {
    //Do something
  }
}

class ElementReceiver {
  private StreamProcessor A;
  private StreamProcessor B;
  private StreamProcessor C;

  public synchronized void onNewElementReceived(Element e) {
    if(e.type() /*Whatever*/ == ElementType.A) {
       A.add(e);
    }else if(e.type() == ElementType.B) {
       B.add(e);
    }else {
       C.add(e);
    }
  }
}
```

This code consists of four threads.

The first thread receives the Element from some unspecified data source.

If this thread receives one, it checks what type it is (A,B or C).

Each of these types has a corresponding StreamProcessor. The onNewElementReceived will add the received element to the working set of the corresponding StreamProcessor.

Each of these StreamProcessor threads checks until they are for example killed and blocks until it has got an Element and then the method `workWith` is called that has to be implemented by each subclass.

Comment: This actually sounds promising. I will try this. One question though. If we have a single Thread ElementReceiver do we really need a threadsafe list inside the streamProcessor?

Comment: I have done it to avoid potential issues when adding and removing an item to a list at the same time. It may be redundant, you have to try. Better safe than sorry

Comment: I will accept your answer. Seems to be working although it needs some further testing. But this came close to my idea with the looper but actually is smarter:)